# Direct products inside finite simple groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups, direct-product, groups-of-lie-type

For a finite group $G$, let $d(G)$ be the largest $k$ such that $G$ admits a subgroup isomorphic to a direct product of $k$ non-trivial groups. I am interested in families $G_n$ of finite simple groups such that $d(G_n)$ goes to infinity.

Examples are $S_n$ or groups of Lie type in dimension $n$. In both cases, any prime power eventually divides the order of these groups.

I was wondering: it possible to have a family of finite simple groups $G_n$ with $d(G_n)$ going to infinity while this does not happen? So there exists a prime power $q$ such that $q$ never divides the order of $G_n$?

Looking at the list it seems to me that this should not be possible. I don't have a specific requirement on how the $G_n$ should be related to one another but of course it would be nicer to have examples where there is some connection.

Comment: This depends a bit on what you call a family of finite simple groups. How about $G_n = {\rm PSL}(2,2^{2n+1})$? The order is not divisible by $5$ for any $n$.

Comment: Another example is the family of Suzuki groups ${\rm Sz}(2^{2n+1})$. Their orders are not divisible by $3$ (they are the only finite nonabelian simple groups with that property).

Comment: If you bound the Lie rank of the family $(G_n)$ then you can always find infinitely many groups that don't embed at all into any $G_n$. On the other hand, if you allow the Lie rank of $(G_n)$ to tend to infinity then I think one may produce an arbitrary direct product of any finite group, but I would have to check that. There might be some cunning characteristic thing you can do to stop that, but I think not.

Comment: Actually, now I read your question again I'm not sure what you actually want.

Comment: @DerekHolt right, but does the quantity $d(G)$ tend to infinity? That's the main point: there are many ways to avoid specific primes but those I thought of ask for the dimension to stay fixed, and I don't know then how to find large direct products inside

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I am looking for finite simple groups $G_n$ such that $d(G_n)$ goes to infinity but you can still avoid certain prime powers from dividing their order

Comment: Ah, only prime powers. Well, that's much easier. The easiest examples are things like Derek's. Take any Lie type group $G(p^a)$, choose $q$ a prime large enough and then 'most' prime powers $p^a$ satisfy $q\nmid G(p^a)$. If you let the rank tend to infinitity then it should be fine. Clearly there are not infinitely many $G(p^a)$ where $p\mid q$. For all sufficiently large ranks all cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_d(p^a)$ divide $|G(p^a)|$ for $1\leq d\leq q-1$, and this means that $q$ divides all sufficiently large-rank $G(p^a)$. With larger lower bounds on the rank you can do prime powers.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven but what confuses me is how you can get for instance a direct product of 3, 4, 5 groups inside $PSL_2$

Comment: For your other comment, about $d(G)$ growing, this is true for any finite simple group. If one bounds the $p$-rank of a finite simple group for all primes $p$ then the order of the group is bounded. For Lie type groups, $\mathbb{F}_{p^a}$ lies in $G(p^a)$, so there's a large number of copies of a $p$-group.

Comment: @frafour Yes, a Sylow $2$-subgroup of ${\rm PSL}(2,2^{2n+1})$ is the direct product of $2n+1$ cyclic groups of order $2$.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I see, so that's a cool and versatile example, thanks!

Comment: @DerekHolt so just to close this off with respect to your previous comment, how does one embed $\mathbb{F}_q$ inside $Sz(q)$?

Comment: A Sylow $2$-subgroup $P$ of ${\rm Sz}(q)$ has order $q^2$, with $Z(P)$ and $P/Z(P)$ both isomorphic to $({\mathbb F}_q,+)$ (i.e. elementary abelian of order $q = 2^{2n+1}$).